# How to access the value of a custom attribute in data from highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have this in my code

```
    series: [{
      name: 'Velocidad',
      turboThreshold: 5000,
      data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
              i;
          for (i = 0; i < valor; i++) {
              data.push({
                  x: dataUtc[i],
                  y: dataVel[i],
                  id: i
              });

          }
          return data;
      })(),
      tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 0,
          valueSuffix: 'Kms/H'
      }
  }]
```

When I try to get the maximum value I only get the `x` or `y` value.
I need to get the **`id`** value though.
What can I do?

I tried the following:

```
var chart = $('#containerVelocidad').highcharts();

min = chart.xAxis[0].min;
max = chart.xAxis[0].max;
```

Unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by `id value`?

Comment: Which values you nee to get, min/max from serie ?

Comment: my series is composed of x = datetime utc,y = speed and id = sequential.I can get the maximum and minimum value of x = utc datetime but i can´t get the variable id assigned by my.i need get the id variable from the serie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use `yAxis.dataMax` not `yAxis.max`. The second one is returning actual extremes, when sometimes you may have different extremes, than just from one series (zooming, setting extremes, multiple series etc.).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ez4hjazk/1/

And code:

```
    var max = chart.yAxis[0].dataMax,
        maxIndex = chart.series[0].yData.indexOf(max), //get index from yData, read more about .indexOf() !
        data = chart.series[0].data;

    // make sure point is within actual extremes
    if(maxIndex > -1) {
        console.log("max = " + max, 'id = ' + data[maxIndex].id);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering. i need the extreme value of id from navigation bar. the code example http://jsfiddle.net/3q0t79cn/21/

Comment: The problem is that `yData` contains all y-values. Meanwhile `data` contains only existing points on a chart (rendered ones). So correlation between them in Highstock is missing, so you can't use my snippet. I think it would be easiest to loop over all `data` array and find correct point by comparing y-value, sorry.

Comment: @PawełFus Dear Pawel, he has assigned an `id` attribute and I think he wants that one's min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get the maximum/minimum of `id`?

If so, try `chart.series[0].data[i].id`. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ez4hjazk/

Comment: thanks for answering. i need the extreme value of id from navigation bar. the code example http://jsfiddle.net/3q0t79cn/21/

Comment: @MauricioRiquelme Dear Mauricio, I assigned some `id` attributes to my example and tried to get the `min` and `max` of them. Review my example please and let us know if you want the `min` and `max` of your own assigned attribute `id`: http://jsfiddle.net/ez4hjazk/